# Database Modeling - An alternate method to avoid duplication of records

Tags: database-design, oracle-sqldeveloper, data-modeling

I'm modeling a Database specification using Oracle SQL Data Modeler. My question concerns 3 entities, **Sales_Rep**, **Consult_Skills** and **Article_Group**. The specification describes that a Sales Representative sells articles (read: products) of which belong to a certain article group. However, it must also be shown that sales reps have a level of skill regarding cetrain article groups. Therefore, I created the entity Consult_Skills with a Primary Key 'Skill_ID', and 2 Foreign Keys from the Sales_Rep and Article_Group entities. This way the Consult_Skills table will be able to tell me the skill level of every sales rep, for selling each article group. This naturally creates some duplicate columns, as there are multiple article groups, a sales rep will be listed more than once, to describe their skill relating to other article groups.

So my main question is, is there an alternative to showing the skill level, in a way I can avoid duplicate columns? The design should ideally be scalable, meaning new article groups could be added.

**The Logical Design:**

[image]

**Consult_Skills Attributes**

[image]

Comment: The triplet `(person_id, skill_level_id, article_group_id)` will be unique - what duplication do you have in mind ?

Comment: Indeed, there is no duplication - CONSULT_SKILLS is an entity capturing many-to-many relationship between Sales Reps and Article Groups (one Sales Rep can sell from multiple Article Groups, one Article Group can be sold by multiple Sales Reps). So, in this table Sales Rep Id can appear multiple times, Article Group Id can appear multiple times, but (Sales Rep Id, Article Group Id) combination will be unique.